# Cannot scan from Brother MFC-J825DW using the buttons on the printer

Tags: scanner, brother-printer

When I try to use the printer and select Scan > Email, it goes through the motions and suddenly stop with an error on the computer screen. It used to work before. I can print also.

[Minus http://i.minus.com/i6CLBUbsJnvmb.png](http://i.minus.com/i6CLBUbsJnvmb.png)

Reference:

http://welcome.solutions.brother.com/bsc/public/us/us/en/faq/faq_list.html?reg=us&c=us&lang=en&prod=mfcj825dw_all&Cat=117

Comment: Are you starting the scan by pressing on of the buttons on the printer, or by selecting "Scan to Email" inside a program?

Comment: @K.A The buttons on the printer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

1. Turn off the printer
2. Uninstall the software on the PC and restart the PC
3. Turn on the printer
4. Connect to it with the PC and let it install the drivers

If it doesn't work after this, I'll be inclined to feel it's a hardware problem. If it does, then we would need to look at software configuration and what may have been changed to cause it to fail.

Comment: I uninstalled, and re-install the printer software and now it works! In the future, I don't believe I will buy a Brother printer.

Comment: Wow, I had to re-install the printer driver again for my laptop now because it wouldn't print! What a drag!